# How do i get the codes for characters in a string?

Tags: python

As an example, how would I get the code for § in python. § is be represented as '\u00a7', but I would like it to give me the code 00a7, so I can use it in the creation of code files.
Also I would like this to work if I just put the letter 'a'

Comment: It's `print u"\u00a7"` in Python 2 and `print("\u00a7")` in Python 3. The u standing for Unicode.

Comment: the answer to that question doesn twork the later works and makes me feel dumb

Comment: `r"\u00a7".split(r'\u')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can [encode](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [decode](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) stings with

```
>>> '§'.encode()
b'\xc2\xa7'
>>> b'\xc2\xa7'.decode()
'§'
```

That is one way of accessing byte codes.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this?

```
c = '\\u' + hex(ord(u'§'))[2:].rjust(4, '0')
print(c)  # Prints \u00a7
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't exactly work since it has a limit of how it can go